# iCal rrule for two different lengths

Tags: icalendar, rrule

I want to enter an event in my calendar that runs on Monday and Tuesdays from 8-3 and Saturdays from 8-12 every week. My app is supporting rrule's. Is it possible to pack that into a single rrule?

If it would be only the weekdays, then the rule would be simple and do look like:

```
FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO,TU
```

Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The duration of the event is not part of the rrule definition but is rather determined by the DTSTART/DTEND or DTSTART/DURATION combinations so there is no way to have one single event representing what you want (unless you create exceptions for every single instances on Saturday)

The best you can do is to use the RELATED-TO property (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.4.5) to link the 2 events.

Comment: I had the same impression, but wanted to confirm first on SO.